# Java. SparkSQL join large datasets

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to join 2 large datasets (2GB json files/10.000.000 tuples each) on a cluster of machines (5 machines) but I always get the same error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

The spark script is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("Java Spark Translator")
.master("local")
.getOrCreate();

StructType rainSchema = new StructType().add("id","integer").add("altitude","double").add("city_name","string").add("latitude","double").add("longitude","double").add("rainfall","double").add("station_name","string").add("time","timestamp");
Dataset<Row> s1 = spark.read().schema(rainSchema).json("dataset/rainfall.json");

StructType humiditySchema = new StructType().add("id","integer").add("altitude","double").add("city_name","string").add("latitude","double").add("longitude","double").add("humidity","double").add("station_name","string").add("time","timestamp");
Dataset<Row> s2 = spark.read().schema(humiditySchema).json("dataset/humidity.json");



Dataset<Row> j1 = s1.join(s2, s2.col("station_name").equalTo(s1.col("station_name")), "inner");

j1.show();
```

Am I doing something wrong? What could be the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste spark submit with arguments here?

Comment: `/home/hadoopuser/spark_test_lf/spark/bin/spark-submit --class "spark.examples.App" --master spark://<url>:7077 target/Java_Spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 0):

You configure spark to use "local" as your master. This means you are not really using the cluster but only a single node. Furthermore, if you haven't set spark defaults for a default size of the executor, you would have only a very small executor (1 GB by default).

This would mean that spark would start reading the data and throwing it away eventually crashing for lack of memory or for GC (if it simply creates and destroys the data too fast).

So the first thing you should do is set your master to whatever resource manager you are using (which means you need to set it up first).

You also need to configure the different executors (how many of them are you using, how much memory for each etc.)

In addition, json is not an efficient format to work with. This means that if you don't have the memory to handle everything, some elements might be evicted and need to be reread (or just something crashes) which would be slow. Worse still, if you have a problem, you always start from scratch.

I would instead write the dataframes (dataset) to parquet file first and then read from parquet and do the join. That way, even if something crashes after generating the parquet files, the next steps would be much faster.

Comment: Thank you. I think I did a mistake on pasting here the code. The `.master("local")` is not present in my code. But I will try to write the parquet and try to run join with them.